# OpenSMTPd: Block sender based on "Received" domain

Tags: email, spam, opensmtpd

For OpenSMTPd, I would like to block a server from sending me mail based on the domain name of that server. It has a large number of IP addresses all over the place and blocking each individual one is far too much work especially with the massive amount of spam it sends. I would like to just outright block the server, is there a way to just silently reject all mail coming in from the mail servers at "example.com" (the "Received" contains this) for example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Received` headers should not be used for determining the origin of the email as they can be easily spoofed. Instead, you should only trust the information your mail server can obtain by itself, such as source address, `HELO` hostname and `MAIL FROM` (tested against the SPF record of the sender domain). The last i.e. the topmost `Received:` header is added by your server, and this information comes from the `HELO` SMTP command (combined with IP address & reverse `PTR`).

Header content inspection would be possible with e.g. Postfix [`header_checks`](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) (action `REJECT`), but it seems OpenSMTPd has not implemented anything similar. Also, OpenSMTPd can only relay mail to external filters, making *connection-stage rejection* for failed SFP or *DNS-based block list* (DNSBL) impossible.

What OpenSMTPd can do that may help is described in `smtpd.conf(5)`, [`match`](https://man.openbsd.org/smtpd.conf#match) *options* `reject`:

- You say there is a *large number of IP addresses all over the place*, but they may all actually be in the same network block. Use e.g. `whois IP.ADD.RE.SS` to determine the subnet as CIDR-notation, as OpenSMTPd is able to read subnets expressed in CIDR-notation, e.g. block `192.0.2.0/24` with:

  ```
  match from src 192.0.2.0/24 reject
  ```
- If you want to *reject all mail coming in from the mail servers at `example.com`* and this domain is really used in the `HELO` hostname, it's possible to use that information for rejection. Similarly, the `match` has an option for that, and you can use a list [`table(5)`](https://man.openbsd.org/table.5) file:

  ```
  match helo <rejectHeloDomains> reject
  table rejectHeloDomains file:/etc/mail/rejectHeloDomains
  ```

  The list file containing the domains, wildcards allowed:

  ```
  example.com
  *.example.com
  ```

Do not silently *discard* definite spam, but use the *connection-stage rejection*, as these examples do.